# Perl Hex CRC-16 bit script

Tags: perl, subroutine, crc

I'm new to perl and i would like to know why the arguments are not correcly passed to the subroutine.
Also, are the output values correct?

```
use strict;

sub crc16 {
     use constant POLY => $_[1];
     my $crc = 0;
     for my $c ( unpack 'C*', $_[0] ) {
         $crc ^= $c;
         for my $b ( 0 .. 7 ) {
             my $carry = $crc & 1;
             $crc >>= 1;
             if( $carry ) {
                 $crc ^= POLY;
             }
         }
     }
     return $crc;
}

my $data = "1234";
my $poly = "0x8005";

printf "crc: %04x\n", crc16( $data, $poly );
```

Thanks!

Comment: I get 0000 as a result, so I'm going to assume that is wrong. Why do you think the arguments get unpacked incorrectly ?

Comment: because i am also getting 0000... if you replace $_[1] with the string directly, it works.

Comment: That's the kind of useful information that *should* go in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `use ...` statement is always executed at *compile time*, and is not subject to normal control flow. During compile time, the `@_` array does not contain elements, so `$_[1]` will be undefined. You should be using regular variables:

```
sub crc16 {
   my ($string, $poly) = @_;
   my $crc = 0;
   for my $c ( unpack 'C*', $string ) {
      $crc ^= $c;
      for ( 0 .. 7 ) {
         my $carry = $crc & 1;
         $crc >>= 1;
         $crc ^= $poly if $carry;
      }
   }
   return $crc;
}
```

Oh, and you should be specifying the `$poly` as an integer, not a string: `$poly = 0x8005`, without the quotes.

---

As I pointed out in a comment on a similar question of yours, there already is a Perl module that implements CRC algorithms: [`Digest::CRC`](https://metacpan.org/module/OLIMAUL/Digest-CRC-0.18/lib/Digest/CRC.pm). The important parts are coded in C for performance. The provided functions are highly parameterizable. I urge you to find a way to use that module instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Laurent Is that string supposed to be hex data, or are the string characters itself to be hashed? You may need to `pack "H*"` it first

Comment: Yes, i'd like to turn a hex input to a hex (crc-16) output

Comment: do i have to pack("H*",$data) before putting it into the function or in the function itself?

Comment: There is a difference between the hex string `"1A"` and the actual number it represents: `26` (case 1). The string itself however can be represented as `0x31 0x41` (case 2). For the interpretation of case 1, you have to translate the data to the binary representation, via `pack "H*"`. I suggest you do this outside the function, to keep your sub as general as possible.